# getElementsByClass java returning null

Tags: javascript, html

```
I have the following part of  document:
    <div class=\"_427x\"> 
     .....                                                                                              <span class=\"_50f7\">.....some text </span>
```

and I have the following code:

```
if (htmlPost.getElementsByClass("\\\"_50f7\\\"")!=null && htmlPost.getElementsByClass("\\\"_50f7\\\"").size()>=1) {
    cFType.setName(htmlPost.getElementsByClass("\\\"_50f7\\\"").get(0).text());
    }
```

The problem is that the size always returns null when I debug.getElementsByClass is not working. Can you please help me?

Comment: `"\\\"_50f7\\\""` is wrong. Use just `"_50f7"`

Comment: getElementsByClass("_50f7") ?

Comment: the size is still returning null :/

Comment: Why are all your quotes in your HTML written like `\"`? Is that a typo in your code? You really don't need to do that in HTML. Just use a normal `"` without the `\`.

Comment: Thats not valid HTML

Comment: this is the given document to me